# Matlab axis error using imagesc

Tags: matlab

I am plotting multiple heatmaps in matlab 3014b using `imagesc` with one common `colorbar`. Here is my code:

```
a(1)= subplot('Position',[0.1, 0.65, 0.3, 0.3]);
data1 = rand(5);
imagesc(data1)
ax = gca; 
ax.XTick = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
ax.XTickLabel = {'0','0.1', '0.2', '0.3','0.4','0.5'};
ax.YTick = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
ax.YTickLabel = {'1','10', '100', '1000', '10000', '100000'};

a(2)= subplot('Position',[0.45, 0.65, 0.3, 0.3]);
data2 = rand(5);
imagesc(data2)
ax = gca; 
ax.XTick = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
ax.XTickLabel = {'0','0.1', '0.2', '0.3','0.4','0.5'};
ax.YTick = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
ax.YTickLabel = {'1','10', '100', '1000', '10000', '100000'};

h=colorbar;
set(h, 'Position', [.8 .135 .0581 .8150])
for i=1:2
      pos=get(a(i), 'Position');
      set(a(i), 'Position', [pos(1) pos(2)]);
end
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error using matlab.graphics.axis.Axes/set
While setting the 'Position' property of Axes:
Value must be a 4 element vector
```

Not exactly sure how to resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is right here:

```
for i=1:2
      pos=get(a(i), 'Position');
      set(a(i), 'Position', [pos(1) pos(2)]); %// <--- here
end
```

Is there a particular reason why you're truncating the last two elements?  `Position` should be a 4 element vector where the first two elements define the distance from the lower-left corner of the container to the lower-left corner of the axes, and the third and fourth element are the width and height of the axes within the window.  If it's your intention to perhaps keep all of the axes the same width/height, do something like this:

```
for i=1:2
      pos=get(a(i), 'Position');
      set(a(i), 'Position', [pos(1) pos(2) 1 1]); %// Change
end
```

Check out the documentation on MathWorks on axes properties... specifically `Position` here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#zmw57dd0e52524